# CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Tags: c#

CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference![enter image description here][1]

this is the problem i get 
i have tried and tried 
The biggest problem is this works on my computer the remote server

Comment: man i installed assemblies runs well while debugging in visual studio but smartasp.net gives me an error

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the mysql library. Install the nuget package manager and run the following:

```
Install-Package MySql.Data
```

See [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/)